# Firebase Login using Mobile number and password (without OTP)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an android app, having an authentication with mobile number and password
(yeah not OTP!!!).
I've read article of custom token but didn't understood.[(this is the link to documentation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#java_2)
Can someone help in implementing this?
(Please show it's implementation using Custom Token)
Thank you in advance!!;)

Answer (score 1):

Custom Auth is a fully custom solution and requires you to setup the additional OAuth provider yourself, which you are most likely not interested in doing.

Instead, you could achieve this by using password Auth by simply appending the project name onto the end as a domain `125132346@myproject-0.com`. This does mean that it's not directly linked to Phone verification and the OTP which you might find ideal. The cool thing is should you need to also link your phone verification in the future, Firebase supports Auth linking.

Password: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Link Auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

**UPDATE**

To implement Custom Tokens, you must have the admin-sdk installed on a cloud service such as Firebase cloud functions. You will then have to redirect the user to the function or invoke it with the user credentials to generate the token, typically this is done with another OAuth provider to prevent spoofing.

The minimal Setup is as follows:
Cloud Function with onRequest

```js
exports.phoneAuth = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const uid = request.body.number; // users phone number from the request

return admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    response.status(200).send(customToken);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
});
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk